# Why ngModelChange event triggering whenever focus in and out on the input box?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodelchange

sample.html

```
<input #gb type="text" pInputText class="ui-widget ui-text" [(ngModel)]
="filterText"  (ngModelChange)="filterText = $event; clearFilter(filterText)"/>
```

componenent.ts

```
 clearFilter(value) {
                alert(value);// values is empty
            }
```

This alert will be fire every focus (in | out) on the input filed . I want to do hit the function if the model object had any changes.

> How to handle it and Why `ngModelChange` event triggering while focus in and out on the input box?

Comment: You can just make `filterText` a getter/setter and call the code in the setter. I doubt the event will be fired on focus. It will probably be fired on `blur` but AFAIR only when the value actually changed.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yeah! am totally tired due to `ngModelChange` event.  Really I don't know why ngModelChange event triggered when I just click the textbox (focus in and out). I have no idea about it.

Comment: what is `pInputText` ?

Comment: @Maximus that is `primeng` directive

Comment: well, create a plunker if you can

Comment: okay. I'll try.

Answer (score 4):

Because their work is to handle changes in the text box 
you have focus and blur methods

```
<input #gb type="text" pInputText class="ui-widget ui-text" 
  [(ngModel)] ="filterText" 
  (ngModelChange)="clearFilter(filterText)"
  (blur)="clearFilter($event)"
  (focus)="clearFilter($event)"/>
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/F3zIAtWkTdTmoTNVy8Fy?p=preview)

Update based on comment

Since you are using `[(ngModel)]` and `(ngModelChange)` it is triggering.

Comment: Actually I don't want to call the `clearfilter();` event while focusing and blur.

Comment: it is just for demo purpose.

Comment: But in my scenario. I don't want to hit any methods  while focus in and out. I just want to call a function once the ng model object have any change.

Comment: it willl not trigger. can u reproduce using aplunk?

Comment: Yes! I already checked it in your plunkr. But I don't know why the same code is hitting here.

Comment: are you setting any values onInit?

Comment: No I just declare that object globally, not initialized

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: Yes! me to on plunkr. but  still am getting this issue in my application.

Comment: OMG! it's working when I remove the variable declaration.

Comment: so is this enough or need more help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149384/discussion-between-ramesh-rajendran-and-aravind).

Comment: I'll not mark us this answer. but I can give a up vote for discussion with me.

Comment: Thats fine. :) Happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

The solution is trackBy if ngModel value change when you use *ngFor

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zwnges?file=app%2Fapp.component.html